# nested structure array access in python using SWIG

Tags: python, arrays, structure, swig

I haven't been able to figure out how to access the array elements SubStatus in the following nested structure.  I do seem to be able to see the first element, but don't understand how to force indexing, e.g., as a list.

Any help is much appreciated.

### status.h:

```
// Data Types
typedef char           CHAR;   // 8 bits signed
typedef short          SHORT;  // 16 bits signed
typedef long           LONG;   // 32 bits signed
typedef unsigned char  UCHAR;  // 8 bits unsigned
typedef unsigned short USHORT; // 16 bits usigned

#define FUNC_TYPE       // built in C, leave reference as C
#define DLL_API extern FUNC_TYPE __declspec(dllimport)

// Sub Status Data
typedef struct
{
    LONG  xyz;                              
    LONG  abc;                                           
} SUB_STATUS;


// Status Info
typedef struct
{
    UCHAR  qrs;             
    UCHAR  tuv;             
    SUB_STATUS SubStatus[4];     
    LONG   wxy;     
} STATUS;

DLL_API  SHORT  GetStatus( STATUS *Status );
```

### status.i

```
%module status
 %{
 /* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
 #include "status.h"
 %}

 /* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
 %include "windows.i"
 %include "typemaps.i" 
 %include "status.h"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWIG/python array inside structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114030/swig-python-array-inside-structure)

Comment: Thanks awoodland, but I don't have control over the .h file as this comes from a vendor's distribution.  If I understood that other solution correctly, I'd have to make modifications to the c source, right?  I am hoping for an answer which just affects the .i file.

Comment: You can apply it without modifying the header, it's a little trickier though. I'll put together an example later hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this header without having to modify it buy doing something like:

```
%module status

%immutable;
%inline %{
template <typename Type, size_t N>
struct wrapped_array {
  Type (&data)[N];
  wrapped_array(Type (&data)[N]) : data(data) { }
};
%}
%mutable;

%{
#include "status.h"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"
%include "std_except.i"

// Only expose a reduced STATUS, without the Array:
typedef struct
{
    UCHAR  qrs;
    UCHAR  tuv;
    LONG   wxy;
} STATUS;

%extend wrapped_array {
  inline size_t __len__() const { return N; }

  inline const Type& __getitem__(size_t i) const throw(std::out_of_range) {
    if (i >= N || i < 0)
      throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds access");
    return $self->data[i];
  }

  inline void __setitem__(size_t i, const Type& v) throw(std::out_of_range) {
    if (i >= N || i < 0)
      throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds access");
    $self->data[i] = v;
  }
}

%template (SubStatusArray) wrapped_array<SUB_STATUS,4>;

// Hide the real array in our helper

%extend STATUS {
  wrapped_array<SUB_STATUS,4> getSubStatus() {
    return wrapped_array<SUB_STATUS,4>($self->SubStatus);
  }
}

%ignore STATUS; // We've specified an alternative way of wrapping this
%include "status.h"
```

This is basically the same as [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203652/168175), but instead of modifying the header to use the `wrapped_array`, we've used `%ignore` to tell SWIG we will supply our own definition of `STATUS` for it to wrap. (This is perfectly legal, the SWIG generated wrapper will still use the real definition from status.h)

We inject into this altered definition a `getSubStatus()`, which returns an object that acts as a proxy to the real array in `STATUS`. This proxy in turn supplies `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__len__` that python looks for to use the subscript operator.

There might be a way to do this properly in Python without needing the `getSubStatus()`, making SWIG set `__swig_setmethods__["SubStatus"]` and `__swig_getmethods__["SubStatus"]` appropriately, but I'm not sure off the top of my head how to make SWIG python do that.

If you're using C, not using C++ you'll want to drop the template in favour of just a plain `struct` and use a pointer instead of a reference to an array.

Comment: Flexo, I am trying to do similar things with python/swig, but in my case I want to use C.  So I did something similar to Lou K's code but used a toy struct, `typdef struct { int i; int ai[10]; } mystruct;`  i tried to override ai with `typdef struct { int data[10]; } wrapped_array_int_10;` and `wrapped_array_int_10* getai()`.  i got the code compiled, but from python when tried `o = example.mystruct()`, i got error that mystruct don't have constructor.  can you tell what am i missing?  thanks...

Comment: @yos are you building in C or C++?

Comment: I am building with c.