# SWIG/python array inside structure

Tags: python, arrays, swig

I've got a structure defined inside header.h that looks like :

```
typedef struct {
....
    int      icntl[40];
    double   cntl[15];
    int      *irn, *jcn;
....
```

When I init an object with this structure, I have access to integers/doubles but not arrays.

```
>> st.icntl
<Swig Object of type 'int *' at 0x103ce37e0>
>> st.icntl[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_mumps.py", line 19, in <module>
    print s.icntl[0]
TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not subscriptable
```

How to have access to the values in read/write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap your arrays inside a `struct`, which can then provide [extra methods to meet the "subscriptable" requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/in-python-what-does-it-mean-if-an-object-is-subscriptable-or-not).

I've put together a small example. It assumes you're using C++, but the equivalent C version is fairly trivial to construct from this, it just requires a bit of repetition.

First up, the C++ header that has the `struct` we want to wrap and a template that we use for wrapping fixed size arrays:

```
template <typename Type, size_t N>
struct wrapped_array {
  Type data[N];
};

typedef struct {
    wrapped_array<int, 40> icntl;
    wrapped_array<double, 15> cntl;
    int      *irn, *jcn;
} Test;
```

Our corresponding SWIG interface then looks something like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
#include <exception>
%}

%include "test.h"
%include "std_except.i"

%extend wrapped_array {
  inline size_t __len__() const { return N; }

  inline const Type& __getitem__(size_t i) const throw(std::out_of_range) {
    if (i >= N || i < 0)
      throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds access");
    return self->data[i];
  }

  inline void __setitem__(size_t i, const Type& v) throw(std::out_of_range) {
    if (i >= N || i < 0)
      throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds access");
    self->data[i] = v;
  }
}

%template (intArray40) wrapped_array<int, 40>;
%template (doubleArray15) wrapped_array<double, 15>;
```

The trick there is that we've used `%extend` to supply [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) which is what Python uses for subscript reads and [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) for the writes. (We could also have supplied a `__iter__` to make the type iteratable). We also gave the specific `wraped_array`s we want to use unique names to make SWIG wrap them in the output.

With the supplied interface we can now do:

```
>>> import test
>>> foo = test.Test()
>>> foo.icntl[30] = -654321
>>> print foo.icntl[30]
-654321
>>> print foo.icntl[40]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 108, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, *args): return _test.intArray40___getitem__(self, *args)
IndexError: out of bounds access
```

You might also find [this approach](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn63) useful/interesting as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I would have done this in python

```
ptr = int(st.icntl)
import ctypes
icntl = ctypes.c_int * 40
icntl = icntl.from_address(ptr)

print icntl[0]
icntl[0] = 1
for i in icntl:
    print i
```

Comment: The question points out the need to use SWIG, and not full Python code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SWIG carrays?

In your header file:

```
typedef struct {
    int      icntl[40];
    double   cntl[15];
} some_struct_t;
```

Then, in your swig file:

```
%module example
%include "carrays.i"  
// ...
%array_class(int, intArray);
%array_class(double, doubleArray);
```

The Python looks like this:

```
icntl = example.intArray(40)
cntl = example.doubleArray(15)
for i in range(0, 40):
    icntl[i] = i
for i in range(0, 15):
    cntl[i] = i
st = example.some_struct_t()
st.icntl = icntl
st.cntl = cntl
```

You still can't set the structs directly. I write python wrapper code to hide the boilerplate.

array_class only works with basic types (int, double), if you need something else (e.g. uint8_t) you need to use array_functions, which have even more boilerplate, but they work.

http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_carrays