# how to wrap array inside C struct/class with SWIG, without changing C code

Tags: c++, swig

How to wrap this

```
class Foobar {
public:
    int member[];
}
```

in SWIG, without changing this C++ code??

Here is an excellent post that explains a lot,

[SWIG/python array inside structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114030/swig-python-array-inside-structure)

but the way it works, you have to change the C++ code to make it possible to wrap.  I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems, like I can just go a step further than in [SWIG/python array inside structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114030/swig-python-array-inside-structure)
I change the above original code `foobar.h` to :

```
class Foobar {
public:
    int_array_wrapper member;
}
```

and then, I can both `#include` and `%include` this `foobar_modified_for_swig.h` in my SWIG interface code, at the same time, the original `foobar.cpp` will still use `foobar.h` and the two link together and appear to work.  Not sure why this works but it seems to work.