# How to expose array of C strings char[M][N] in SWIG?

Tags: python, swig

I have a legacy C/C++ struct like this (with many other members as well):

```
struct S {
  char one_name[MAX_LEN];
  char names[N_NAMES][MAX_LEN];
}
```

and a C function that creates these:

```
S *get_S(...)
```

I'd like to export S and names via swig so I can do this in python:

```
s = MyModule.get_S()
print s.one_name # I have this working
print s.names[1] # should print the 2nd string, this is harder
```

I assume I need some kind of typemap but I'm new to swig.  I can do `one_name` with the wrapped_array template as in [SWIG/python array inside structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114030), but I'm not sure how to extend that to an array of strings.  I only need to read these strings from python (as above), not write them.  I can do it with an accessor so the python would look like:

```
print s.get_name(i) # prints the ith name
```

but I'd prefer the array interface just because it's similar to the C one.

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't using std::string? SWIG handles it automatically.

Comment: @Schollii: I can't change the underlying interface I'm wrapping; it's ancient C code.  If I need to I can write an accessor function though instead of exposing the string array directly.  I was just hoping I could expose it in a pythonic way, yet as similar to the existing C code as possible so it would be familiar to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to read them from python, then a quick solution is to create an adapter class that uses `std::string`s, and an adapter function. This all goes in the .i file via %inline, you'll also need %rename and probably %ignore. Example,

```
%ignore(S)
%rename(S) Swrap
%rename(get_S) get_SWrap
%newobject get_Swrap

%inline %{
struct Swrap
{
     inline Swrap(S* s): one_name(s.one_name) 
     {
          for (i=0; i<N_NAMES; ++i)
               names[i] = s.names[i];
          // no longer need s:
          delete s; 
     }

     string one_name;
     string names[N_NAMES];    
};

Swrap* get_Swrap() {
    return new Swrap(get_S());
}
%}
```

Comment: If I understand your solution, I think I wasn't clear.  When I said I only need to read the strings, I meant read from python (my S struct is created and managed on the C side).  Your solution works for strings that are read-only on the C side.  Maybe there's a similar idea that works the other way though, I'll think about it more.  I'm learning that Swig has lots of hooks for replacing just about anything.

Comment: In your code, you create an S, then modify its data members. Do you need to do more than that, like pass it to an exported C++ function that modifies data member? Can you please extend your question with examples of operations you want to do from python, this will help a lot.

Comment: I updated the question, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: I updated my answer. Note that %extend is very powerful and might make this even simpler.

Comment: @garyo looks like you accepted, but no upvote; still not clear, or other reason?

Comment: In my real case, I won't be able to make a simple copy of the original, since the underlying object is more dynamic, but this does point me in the right direction -- thanks!