# SWIG C++: Access pointer inside struct

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a struct as shown below defined in my header file (myheader.h)

```
typedef struct
{
    MyMemberStruct* member;
    int32_t n_members;
} MyMember;

MyMember* MyMemberCreate(...)
```

The SWIG interface file

```
%module members

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "myheader.h"
%}

%include "myheader.h"
```

In the function `MyMemberCreate()` a list of `n_members`members are created and stored in `member`.

In Python I would to access these members like:

```
pyMember = members.member[0]
```

But this gives the following error:

> 'MyMemberStruct' object does not support indexing

I have learnt that I can add the following to the interface file

```
%extend MyMember {
    MyMemberStruct __getitem__(int32_t index) {
        if (index < $self->n_members) {
            return $self->member[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Then from Python I can access the members as

```
pyMember = members[0]
```

which should me give me the first index in `MyMemberStruct`

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can achieve the first approach, i.e. `pyMember = members.member[0]` instead?

Comment: Does my older answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8203652/168175 help?