# Swig Interfaces for an Array in a Structure

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a structure like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    int            dof[SIZE_1];                   
    uint32_t       nrOfJoints;                          
    uint32_t       jointAxisId[SIZE_2];                                           
} MY_STRUCT;
```

I need to be able to set and get the values of the arrays dof and jointAxisId from python.

Any help/ suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

So far I have tried using the %extend directive to overload the **getitem** and **setitem** but I can only make it work for a single array at a time.

I am trying to get a typemap working like so :

```
#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
%typemap(in) (int dof[SIZE1]) {
    unsigned int dataSize = ROCKS_MECH_MAX_DOF;
    $1 = new int[dataSize];
    // Is the input a list
    if (PyList_Check($input)){
      //Is the size of the list <= SIZE_1
      if(PyList_Size($input) <= dataSize){
          for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++){
            PyObject *item = PyList_GetItem($input, i);
            //Convert PyObject to C++ int
            int res = SWIG_AsVal_int(item, &$1[i]);
            $1[i] = res;
          }
      }
    }
}

%typemap(argout) (int dof[ROCKS_MECH_MAX_DOF]) {
    unsigned int dataSize = ROCKS_MECH_MAX_DOF;
    PyObject* r = PyList_New(dataSize);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
        PyObject *o = SWIG_From_long_SS_long($1[i]);
        PyList_SetItem(r,i,o);
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, r);
    delete [] $1;
}
#endif
```

but am facing errors here too.
I can't make any changes to the arrays as suggested here [SWIG/python array inside structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114030/swig-python-array-inside-structure) since the arrays are used in several other places.

Comment: Why don't you expose the whole structure as a type to Python? SWIG Python already has good support for transforming C++ arrays to Python lists.